# My app crashes at Startup

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am beginner to android studio. Trying to put some hands on basic API call using Retrofit, for PHP API calls, for login. Sorry please correct me if my way of asking such question might be wrong.

**Code:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefConfig = new PrefConfig(this);
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class); //Here


        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            if (prefConfig.readLoginStatus()) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new WelcomeFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new LoginFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything goes fine when i comment the line labeled Here.

Error From The Log:

```
Process: com.example.surya.emorecomender, PID: 9729
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.surya.emorecomender/com.example.surya.emorecomender.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://10.0.2.2/database_api
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://10.0.2.2/database_api
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:513)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:456)
        at com.example.surya.emorecomender.ApiClient.getApiClient(ApiClient.java:13)
        at com.example.surya.emorecomender.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: Could you please add your error details from the log console?

Comment: Please view my edit, i've added the error from log console.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://10.0.2.2/database_api` this line describe your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most important part:

```
Process: com.example.surya.emorecomender, PID: 9729
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.surya.emorecomender/com.example.surya.emorecomender.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://10.0.2.2/database_api
```

Copy the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://10.0.2.2/database_api` and google it.

Comment: Thank you, have been waiting to troubleshoot from a week. A point, don't forget to view logs. :)

Comment: Exactly. Happy coding. Using Log class in your code also. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log)